# Java - how to improve on this function (Java 8 streams)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've coded a function that finds the unique characters in a string using Java 8 streams, based on an example [here](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/).

To me, it's pretty non-intuitive, maybe because I'm still learning streams. Is there any way to make this more readable?

Here's the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "aabcddeffg";

        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i< charArray.length; i++){
            String myChar = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);
            strList.add(myChar);
        }

        Map<String, Long> myMap =
                strList.stream().
                        collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()
                                )
                        );

        myMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (v == 1) {
                System.out.println(k);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: That's because the name `str` is already used. Use another name and you'll be fine.

Comment: You're right - I noticed that and changed the question to improve readability, but you've answered the question.

Comment: Note that Code Review is generally the place to go for suggestions for improvement on working code.

Comment: A final clarification: do you want the unique characters _per string_, or the unique characters across _several_ strings? (basically a call to #flatMap or not)

Comment: It should be a single string - it could be "a quick brown fox" for example.

Comment: @JackBeNimble Just to be certain, you were looking for a improved version using streams and not an improved method that might not use streams.

Comment: Note. Instead of creating a strList you can just do `Arrays.stream(str.split("")).collect(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculating the actual frequencies, you're pretty much at a minimal example already!

```
Map<Integer, Long> charFrequency = strList.stream() //Stream<String>
            .flatMapToInt(String::chars)  //Stream<IntStream> -> IntStream
            .boxed() //IntStream -> Stream<Integer>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( //Map<K, V>
                    Function.identity(), //K == our integers
                    Collectors.counting() //V == the number of them
            ));

charFrequency.entrySet().stream() //Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>
            .filter(ent -> ent.getValue() == 1) //only entries with value of 1
            .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey) //Stream<Entry> -> IntStream
            .forEach(c -> {
                System.out.println("Found unique character: " + ((char) c));
            });
```

And for doing it for a single string, it's even easier (you save the conversions):

```
Map<Integer, Long> charFrequency = someString.chars() //Stream<Integer>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( //Map<K, V>
                    Function.identity(), //K == our integers
                    Collectors.counting() //V == the number of them
            ));
```

To that end, I would ensure that your code is simply consistent and readable. Use consistent indentation and comment how the stream steps per line, for example.

**Edit**: I've left the below (old) answer just to be informative for the OP, but it doesn't answer the actual question.

Well, there's always [Stream#distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--).

Calcuating the "distinct" (not *unique*) characters:

```
List<Integer> distinctChars = strList.stream() //Stream<String>
        .flatMapToInt(String::chars)  //Stream<IntStream> -> IntStream
        .distinct() //unique IntStream
        .boxed() //unique Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //List<Integer>

distinctChars.forEach(c -> {
    System.out.println("Found distinct char: " + ((char) (int) c));
});
```

If you want to avoid collecting it, you can also avoid all the hassle around the type boxing:

```
strList.stream() //Stream<String>
        .flatMapToInt(String::chars)  //Stream<IntStream> -> IntStream
        .distinct() //unique IntStream
        .forEach(c -> {
            System.out.println("Found distinct char: " + ((char) c));
        });
```

Comment: Wow, that is so good. Thanks for the comments on the right as well.

Comment: 1. The code doesn't compile. 2. Even if it did, the output won't match.

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling it. "str ->" is already defined, but when I change the name, I get a message about "no instances of type variable(s) R exist so that inStream conforms to Stream<? extends R>".

Comment: Apologies on that, fixed @JackBeNimble

Comment: Don't want to do this over and over but the output won't match op's. He wants to print the elements with frequency 1 only.

Comment: Ah, frequency matching. Why didn't I pick up on that? One more final tweak...

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash that question itself is worthless imo, but the answers are worthwhile. There's an option somewhere for people with more rep / mod powers to merge answers to a question into a different question, I think that's what should be done. Would need a duplicate question link for another SO post

Answer (score 1):

Where here is one rather obscure way of doing it.

- Create a stream of `0` to `string length`.
- now find if the string starting at i+1 has any character starting at i, if so it must be a duplicate.
- So pass the index in the stream.
- then map that index to the actual character.
- and reduce a copy of the original string by removing all the duplicates.

```
String str = "aabcddeffg";

String result = IntStream.range(0,str.length())
.filter(i->str.substring(i+1)
        .indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0 )
.mapToObj(i->str.substring(i,i+1)).reduce(str, (a,b)->a.replace(b,""));

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
bceg
```

Comment: have a free counter-upvote, looks correct to me. That said, you'll be making a lot of unecessary substrings.

Comment: @Rogue Yes.  Perhaps it was because it wasn't efficient (which I recognize).  Of course, if efficiency was the goal, then using a few HashSets would have been useful. But thanks!